# set List filters in ExtJS grid dynamically from response

Tags: list, extjs, filter, extjs5, extjs-grid

- I am trying to set(check) List filters of a grid column dynamically
  from response.
- I am able to set them but when I open the menu of the corresponding
  filter and setting some other combination of data to filter
  dynamically it is getting selected and later cleared.
- Is the code am using below for setting filters is right?Need help.

  ```
   var gridFilter = currentGrid.columns[i].filter;
   gridFilter.setActive(true);
   gridFilter.filter.value="SELECTED,REJECTED"; //putting static data for now
   gridFilter.filter.setValue(["SELECTED", "REJECTED"]);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to add and Edit filter for ExtJs is FilterBy method:

```
grid.getStore().filterBy(function(rec, id)) { 
    return (rec.get("DynamicRecName")=="DynamicFilterRecord");
}
```

If you want to edit existing then just remove current filters:

```
grid.getStore().clearFilters()
```

Comment: Store contains filters in **store.Filters** properties. If you want to filters grid then just use this code.

`grid.getStore().clearFilters()

grid.getStore().filterBy(function(rec, id)) { 
    return (rec.get("DynamicRecName")=="DynamicFilterRecord");
}`